# How Total derivative got converted into partial derivative?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, notation

While studying the book Heat and Thermodynamics by Zemansky and RH Dittman, in the topic 'equation for a hydrostatic system' (page no. 88) it was given

[image: red squared dv/dt]

in equation 4.12, when we take Pressure P constant, how the ***dv/dt*** (marked in red sqaure) got converted into ***partial derivative***? (marked in red square)
[image]

Comment: V is a function of P, T,and you are treating one variable as a constant

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your equations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write
$$dV=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_TdP+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdT,$$
then
$$\frac{dV}{dT}=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T\frac{dP}{dT}+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P.$$
If the pressure is constant $dP=0$, and the first term drops out
$$\frac{dV}{dT}=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P.$$